# Type conversion and inheritance

Tags: groovy, casting

given a class like

```
class MyDate extends java.util.Date {
   //add some functionality
}
```

you create your own `Date` Object which inherits all functionality.

But if you try to use this functionality like this

```
MyDate d = MyDate.parse('yyyy','2013')
```

you will run into the problem that the parse method will return a `java.util.Date` which can't be casted to your `MyDate`.

You can write your own cast through the `asType()` functionality, but this will not help, because you would have to add it to the `Date()` class (I know that's possible, but I would like to avoid it).

Is there another way to solve this Problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groovy's `Date.parse` method will return a Date object. If you want it to return your `MyDate` object, you have to write it (overriding, but still using the super):

```
@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors class MyDate extends java.util.Date {
  static MyDate parse(String format, String date) {
    new MyDate( Date.parse(format, date).time )
  }

  String formated() {
    format 'dd/MM/yyyy'
  }
}

MyDate d = MyDate.parse('yyyy-MM-dd','2013-09-03')

assert d.formated() == "03/09/2013"
```

You will also need to inherit the constructors (through this groovy transform) or write your own constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Ralf, you are trying to inherit a static method as if it would be an instance method. This doesn't work. Doing a:

```
Date date = MyDate.parse(....)
```

Will work, but I wouldn't recommend it, since it's confusing: it seems like the parse method is on the MyDate, but in reality you're still calling the static parse method from Date.

Alternatively. you could implement the parse method on your MyDate class, and have that parse method return a MyDate class.

Comment: I wanted to avoid implementing my own parse method - isn't that what inheritance is for? Even if I implement my own method, I run into the problem of casting (I guess I would use the `Date.parse()` method to implement it :-) And I would have to check all other methods to see which ones I would have to re-implement (`clearTime, minus, next, plus` ...) .

Comment: If you would implement your own, there's no problem of casting because it would return the type of class the method is defined in. You'd just use the Date.parse, and build your MyDate with it, either using a copy constructor or pass the time in millis.

Answer (score 0):

The parse method of the object Date (deprecated) does not return a Date object but a static long. Maybe you meant SimpleDateFormat instead ?

Anyway, you have to overload the method you need in this case.

Comment: You are partly right - groovy uses the Groovy JDK, not the JDK. In the Groovy JDK, parse is not deprecated and returns a Date: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Marc, this is Groovy we're talking about. The method has not been deprecated, as can be seen here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just do something like this:

```
MyDate d = (MyDate)Date.parse('yyyy','2013'); //tell me if i'm wrong but i'm pretty sure i'm not
```

and then add the missing members from class MyDate to the new returned object.